# package.update issues and "Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package"

Tags: r, install.packages

I have been having issues loading tidyverse today - it was working fine just 2 days ago - as I kept receiving messages specifying that -vctrs- and -tibble- were out of date:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j = 0.3.8 is required
```

so I opted for updaing packages:

```
update.packages()
```

It all seemed to work correctly but I then received the following error message for several packages:

```
package ‘ellipsis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘ellipsis’
Warning: restored ‘ellipsis’
```

I then decided to save the packages to my library rather than the system one and opted for binary version as several of them had the following message:

```
  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
tibble  3.1.3  3.1.4              TRUE
```

Specifying:

```
install.packages("vctrs", type="binary", "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0")
install.packages("ellipsis", type="binary", "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0")
install.packages("tibble", type="binary", "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0")
install.packages("tidyverse", type= "binary", "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0")
install.packages("broom",  type= "binary", "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0")

###LOAD package
library(vctrs, lib.loc = "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0" )
library(tibble , lib.loc = "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0")
library(ellipsis , lib.loc = "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0")
library(broom, lib.loc = "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0")
library(tidyverse, lib.loc = "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0")
```

This worked and I can then load the package from my personal library and it seems to work correctly but I am not sure why I could not update the packages in the system library - could it be because I don't have administrative rights?  If not, what can I do to force an update of the system library by removing prior installation of packages?

Comment: try restarting your computer as a simple solution. my guess is your .dll files are locked by another R process or something similar.

Comment: If you are also admin for you computer, if you start R as an admin, then you will be able to overwrite files without issue.

Comment: I am not the admin, could this be the reason why I am having these problems? even after restarting the PC the R session opens up and I still get the same error messages, unless I save the packages to my personal library (and also load them from there).